# Get current ApplicationUser from class in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm trying to get the information for the current signed in ApplicationUser from a class.

I was able to achieve this in a controller like this:

```
private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager)
{
    _userManager = userManager;
}

private Task<ApplicationUser> GetCurrentUserAsync() => _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
```

However, when I try this in a class I get an error for both the `_usermanager` and `HttpContext` saying that an object reference is required.

I tried this, however, I can't seem to access the user's information with this method. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var contextAccessor = services.GetRequiredService<IHttpContextAccessor>();
var user = contextAccessor.HttpContext.User;
```

Comment: Is it necessarily appropriate to be doing that in a service class? In theory, that service could be executing on a different machine under a different user account. Should you not be getting the user ID in the controller and passing that to the service?

Comment: @jmcilhinney Sorry, it's not a service class. I'm very new to ASP.NET and got the terminology wrong.

Comment: I have a ShoppingCart Class with a GetCart method which I am trying to configure as a service in Startup.cs so I dont think using a controller would work in my situation

Answer (score 0):

Your controller's User property provides direct access to the user principal object. i.e. System.Security.Principal.IPrincial.

this.User;

this.User.Identity provides the Indentity of that user, which is probably from your authentication alias Identity provider.

Answer (score 0):

```
HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId()
```